# Is the noun phrase "all the way" modifying the prepositional phrase in "all the way around the corner"?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases

> The line stretched all the way around the corner.

Is the NP "all the way" modifying the PP "around the corner"?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150399/discussion-on-question-by-cookie234-is-the-noun-phrase-all-the-way-modifying-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the NP "all the way" modifying the PP "around the corner"?

Yes. There are a number of noun phrases indicating spatial or temporal extent that can modify prepositional phrases. Similar examples include "a long time" in "This happened a long time after the accident" ([Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), p. 644).

Comment: There are also single words that can modify PPs. _It is just behind the door_ / _He putted it right into the hole_ / _She hit the target dead in the middle_.  / _This took place long after the accident_.

Answer (score 0):

"All the way" is an idiom that means  "completely", in many cases, but it has another meaning.

> (**SOED**) **all the way** completely
>                  **all the way (from — to —)** (**a**) Throughout the specified interval, at every point in it;
>                                                                         (**b**) (*US*) (estimated, etc.) at any amount between the specified quantities.

Given the most likely meaning of "line" in this sentence, that is "waiting line" or "queue", the sentence can be read as follows, where, as shown in the definition, "from" and "to" are ellipted (there seems to be an imprecision and the parenthesis should probably be "(**from — to**))".

- The line stretched all the way **from** here **to** around the corner.

Given this understanding, the adverb "all the way" is a clause element adverbial, not a modifier of the PP "around the corner".

**Addition**: As I am for now unable to use the ELU chat (generalized ban on chats du to suspension of account on FSE—however justifiable that is) there follows an answer to a final comment by user Lambie (
*@LPH  People here always seem to forget that communication takes place with utterances in context, pragmatically: "All the way might be one way to go instead of just half-way". all the way there is a noun phrase and also the subject of the sentence. Lambie
@Lambie I don't quite agree with that: you can do the same thing with the adverb "when" ("When is not what they asked.", for instance); yet no dictionary classifies "when" as a noun.
@LPH Adverbials (single words or phrases) are modifiers. "He went all the way with that girl".
@Lambie Yes, they can be called modifiers (of the verb); however, they are not the same sort as adverbs modifying adjectives or PP''s: in those two latter cases the adverb is not a clause element, whereas the adverb as an adverbial always is. LPH
@LPH Yes, so what? They aren't the same. The point is you said they weren't. Lambie*)

@Lambie I suppose that you are referring to these words in my answer (there is nothing else in it and  in my comments from which to elicit your 'you said they werent", otherwise, you'll have to be more specific.): 'is a clause element adverbial, not a modifier of the PP "around the corner"'. This means that the adverb is not a part of the PP, not a modifier of this PP; in your words (and that of some grammarians), the adverb is a modifier of the verb "stretch". I consider that it is the stretching that is all the way, not the aroundness (at the corner).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150395/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-is-the-noun-phrase-modifying-the-prepositional-phras).** Please do not continue the discussion here.